# Anatomy of a monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm trying to learn monad transformers, based on the standard Haskell libraries (mtl?  transformers?  not sure which one came with my download of the Haskell platform - 7.4.1).

What I believe I've noticed is a common structure for each monad transformer definition:

1. base type ('Base')

   - Monad instance
2. transformer type ('BaseT')

   - Monad instance
   - MonadTrans instance
   - MonadIO instance
3. transformer class ('MonadBase')

   - some operations
   - instances for other 'BaseT's

So for example, for the Writer monad, there'd be:

- a Writer datatype/newtype/type, with a Monad instance
- a WriterT datatype/newtype/type, with Monad, MonadTrans, and MonadIO instances
- a MonadWriter class, and instances of this class for StateT, ReaderT, IdentityT, ...

Is this how monad transformers are organized?  Am I missing anything/do I have any incorrect details?

The motivation for this question is figuring out:

1. what the relationships and differences are between the "BaseT"s and the corresponding "MonadBase"s and "Base"s
2. whether all three are required
3. how MonadTrans is related and what its purpose is

Comment: Excellent resource on monads and transformers:  http://monads.haskell.cz/html/index.html

Answer (score 4):

`mtl` package doesn't implement monad transformers. At least WriterT is just [reexported](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/2.1.2/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Writer-Lazy.html) from `transformers`.

`transformers` package implements `WriterT`, which is a monad transformer itself. `Writer` is just an alias:

```
type Writer w = WriterT w Identity
```

Some libraries can implement `Writer` separately, but anyway it is just a special case of `WriterT`. (`Identity` is a trivial monad, it doesn't have any additional behavior.)

`MonadTrans` allows you to wrap underlying monad into the transformed one. You can live without it, but you will need to perform manual wrapping (see `MonadTrans` instance definition for `WriterT` for example how to do it). The only use case where you really need `MonadTrans` -- when you don't know actual type of transformer.

`MonadWriter` is a type class declared in `mtl`. It's methods (`writer`, `pass`, `tell` and `listen`) are the same as function for `WriterT`. It allows to wrap (automatically!) `WriterT` computation through stack of transformers, even if you don't know exact types (and even number!) of transformers in the stack.

So, `WriterT` is the only type which is "required".

For other monad transformers it is the same: `BaseT` is a transformer, `Base` is a monad without underlying monad and `MonadBase` is a type class -- class of all monads, that have `BaseT` somewhere in transformers stack.

**ADDED:**

You can find great explanation in [RWH book](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html)

Here is a basic example:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader hiding (ask)

-- `ask` from transformers
-- ask :: Monad m => ReaderT r m r
import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.Reader as TransReader (ask)

-- `ask` from mtl
-- ask :: MonadReader r m => m r
import qualified Control.Monad.Reader as MtlReader (ask)

-- Our monad transformer stack:
-- It supports reading Int and writing String
type M m a = WriterT String (ReaderT Int m) a

-- Run our monad
runM :: Monad m => Int -> M m a -> m (a, String)
runM i action = runReaderT (runWriterT action) i

test :: Monad m => M m Int
test = do
  tell "hello"
  -- v <- TransReader.ask     -- (I) will not compile
  v1 <- lift TransReader.ask  -- (II) ok
  v2 <- MtlReader.ask         -- (III) ok
  return (v1 + v2)

main :: IO ()
main = runM 123 test >>= print
```

Note that `(I)` will be rejected by compiler (try it to see the error message!). But `(II)` compiles, thanks to `MonadTrans` ("explicit lifting"). Thanks to `MonadReader`, `(III)` works out of the box ("implicit lifting"). Please read RWH book for explanation how it works.

(In the example we import `ask` from two different modules, that is why we need qualified import. Usually you will use only one of them at a time.)

> Also I didn't mean to specifically ask about `Writer`.

Not sure I understand... `Reader`, `State` and others use the same schema. Replace `Writer` with `State` and you will have an explanation for `State`.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  However, I think that for someone who knows little about monad transformers -- me :) -- the answer would be improved by some additional clarity and detail.  Perhaps adding some examples would help too; e.g. to demonstrate the difference between `MonadTrans` and `MonadBase`.  Also I didn't mean to specifically ask about `Writer`.  That said, I don't mean to be all negative about the post -- it was helpful and appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, still not quite clicking.  I kind of get what you wrote, but if I were to implement a transformer myself I wouldn't know where to start -- I don't know what the key concepts are or how they fit together.  Guess it will just take some hard work!

Comment: "A monad transformer is just a pointed endofunctor in the category of monads. What's your problem?"